# Wget Hanging, Script Stops

Tags: http, httprequest, wget, xargs

Evening,

I am running a lot of wget commands using xargs

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -q -t 2 --timeout 10 --dns-timeout 10 --connect-timeout 10 --read-timeout 20
```

However, once the file has been parsed, some of the wget instances 'hang.' I can still see them in system monitor, and it can take about 2 minutes for them all to complete.

Is there anyway I can specify that the instance should be killed after 10 seconds? I can re-download all the URLs that failed later.

In system monitor, the wget instances are shown as sk_wait_data when they hang. xargs is there as 'do_wait,' but wget seems to be the issue, as once I kill them, my script continues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
wget -v -t 2 --timeout 10
```

According to the docs:

- --timeout: Set the network timeout to seconds seconds.  This is equivalent to specifying
  --dns-timeout, --connect-timeout, and --read-timeout, all at the same time.

Check the verbose output too and see more of what it's doing.

Also, you can try:

```
timeout 10  wget -v -t 2
```

Or you can do what timeout does internally:

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 10; kill $cmdpid) & exec wget -v -t 2 )
```

*(As seen in: [BASH FAQ entry #68: "How do I run a command, and have it abort (timeout) after N seconds?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068))*

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. I'm looking at the verbose output, but there's so much that if there was something here I don't think I'll see it.

Comment: Also, `-v` is superfluous. "The default output is verbose." (man wget)

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel can download in parallel, and retry the process after a timeout:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel -j10 --timeout 10 --retries 3 wget -q -t 2
```

If the time for an url to be fetched changes (e.g. due to faster internet connection), you can let GNU Parallel figure out the timeout:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel -j10 --timeout 1000% --retries 3 wget -q -t 2
```

This will make GNU Parallel record the median time for a successful job and set the timeout dynamically to 10 times that.